# Passing parameters and giving them values causes runtime error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

So I have the following code:

```
void emptyString(char* token, int size) {
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) token[i] = '\0';
}

    void setDefaults(char uloginName[], char *home_directory, char *password, char *shell, char *gecos) {
        emptyString(home_directory, sizeof(home_directory) - 1);
        strcat(home_directory, "home/home/");
        strcat(home_directory, uloginName);
    }

    int main(){
        char buffer[256];
        AccountInfo *tempAccount;
        UserDB users;
        char uloginName[9] = "Smith";
        char homeDirectory[33];
        int userID;
        int groupID;
        char password[17];
        char shell[17];
        char gecos[65];
        int i, j, k;
        char flag[3];
        char IDString[6];
        char command[11];
        char blank = ' ';

    setDefaults(uloginName, homeDirectory, password, shell, gecos);
    return 0;
    }
```

When I run this code in Visual Studio I get a pop up window saying

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'users' was
>   corrupted

This is caused due to the lines of codes in the `setDefaults()` method. I was hoping someone helped me to correct the code. My intention is to set the value of home_directory to "*home/home/userloginname*" where userloginname would be one of the variables being passed as well.

EDIT: I just found out the prolem in my code is the `strcat()` method. If I use `strcpy()` for the first one, it works fine, but once I want to add more, it shows me a pop up window saying that the variable `users` got corrupted. Here is the code for the userDB class:

```
class UserDB
{
private:
    AccountInfo* _accounts[200]; // store up to 200 accounts
    unsigned int _size; // number of account stored
    unsigned int _nextUid; // next user id to be assigned
    unsigned int _defaultGid; // default group id
    // other private methods necessary for this class
public:
    // constructors(empty), destructor
    void adduser( AccountInfo* newUser);
    void    showUsers();
    void    showPasswd();
    void    finger(char* userLoginName);class
    int size(); // return the number of accounts stored (_size)
    // and other public methods (mutators/setters, accessors/getters)
};
```

the code is, right now, as it is in here. Perhaps I need to make the constructor or destructor or whatnot, but as a newbie as have no way of knowing what is actually causing the error and needs to be fixed.

EDIT: So after a long while I found out strcat() is what is causing the error, however I need to do what strcat claims to do. Here is a copy of my complete code http://ideone.com/A5iWh so that whoever is interested can let me know what to change because I do not know what else to do. Thanks.

Comment: This code, as written, doesn't compile.  There is no definition for AccountInfo or UserDB.  If I add dummy definitions (i.e. `struct AccountInfo;` and `struct UserDB {};`, the code compiles and runs without error for me (running VC++10).  The error message indicates a stack overflow, but there's no stack overflow in the currently listed code.

Comment: Yes sorry man, I should have know it was better to just post the complete code. [Here it is](http://ideone.com/A5iWh). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So after a long while I found out strcat() is what is causing the error, however I need to do what strcat claims to do. Here is a copy of my complete code http://ideone.com/A5iWh so that whoever is interested can let me know what to change because I do not know what else to do. Thanks and sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: You can fix the compiler errors by adding `#include <cstdlib>` and `#include <cstring>` to the beginning of your source file.

Comment: Oh my, is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
emptyString(home_directory, sizeof(home_directory) - 1);
```

You have n problem here:

```
sizeof(home_directory)
```

This statement gives you size of the pointer `home_directory`, not the array.
If you want the size of array inside the function then you will have to pass it explicitly as an function parameter.

Also, further, Your variables are not initialized causing Undefined Behavior.
Specifically, in the code snippet shown `uloginName`.
You will need to initialize all of your variables lest they will cause problems all over your project.

Comment: I just added the emptyString() method. I personally do not see a problem with it, but I would appreciate it if you let me know if there is something wrong with it. It has worked with other methods, though not with the setDefaults() one.

Comment: Your first reasoning of "`sizeof()` giving wrong result" is correct, but I think in the OP's context, it would not give a runtime error.

Comment: @iammilind: I or anyone wouldn't know that unless the OP posted code for `emptyString()` which was posted **After** I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notable problems:

```
// in getNextToken
while ((buffer[i] != delimeter) && (i < 256) && (j < tokenSize))
    token[j++] = buffer[i++];
```

There's no check that you've reached the end of the contents of `buffer[]`, other than a length check.  What if `cin.getline(buffer)` were to read "a username p mypasswd"?  Then:

at line 150, the copy into `command` fills up `command` but never puts a terminating null at the end.  Maybe this isn't a problem...

at line 153 the read into `uloginName` also doesn't insert a terminating null character.

at line 170 the read into `password` reads 16 bytes.  Maybe you'll get lucky with a null terminator, if the password was short enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcat(home_directory, uloginName);
                       ^^^^^^^^^^ uninitialized
```

The reason is `char uloginName[9];` is not initialized inside `main()` which is being passed to `setDefaults(...)` and thus it's **not** guaranteed to be a **nul terminated** string.

The buffer could be overrunning out of bounds and the code goes in *undefined behavior*.

**Update**: From the code you [posted in the link](http://ideone.com/A5iWh), it seems to be in a mess. You haven't initialized the character arrays, as I stated earlier. Moreover, I don't see any range checks performed, so the buffer may overrun easily.

For example, `uloginName` is just of size `9` and it's highly likely that variable value of `k` can be more than that. Which will cause a stack overflow and it will corrupt the values of the adjacent variables declared near to it. Try to use `std::string` instead of naked arrays if you are not comfortable with bound checking yet.

Comment: Oh dang, I forgot to add that too! I'm sorry! but that one was actually initialized! I will change the code right now so that it is initialized to something.

Comment: @RenatoAlegreMarchand, I don't see any error otherwise. Are you sure, you have posted the exact code ? e.g. `char uloginName[9] = "smith";`

Comment: The code is way more complex than that, but the point is that uloginName is initialized way before `setDefaults()` is executed. I can put the whole thing in though if you wish.

Comment: @YokhenDq, may be you can put your minimal needed code in ideone.com and post a link to that as a comment.

Comment: @YokhenDq, check the updated answer. Don't forget to accept (by tick marking right), if you any of the answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates a "stack overflow."  You've got a fixed size buffer of some sort on your program's stack, and you're writing into it more than the buffer can hold.

Whenever you declare a local variable in C or C++, some storage is allocated for it on the running function's stack.  Let me give an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short above=0;
    char buffer[1];
    short below=0;

    strcpy(buffer, "Hello,");
    strcat(buffer, " world!");

    printf("%d %d %s", above, below, buffer);
}
```

So I've declared `buffer` to have enough space to store 1 byte.  I try to put into it the 14 bytes of `"Hello, world!\0"`.  What do I get when I run this program?

```
27762 0 Hello, world!
```

Now, I set 'above' to 0, explicitly.  How did it become 27762?  Well, here's an illustration of what's actually happening:

```
    Stack:
|        ....         |                              |   ...  |
| misc platform stuff |                              | d!\0...|
|---------------------|                              |--------|
| storage for 'above' | 2 bytes = sizeof(short)      |   rl   |
|---------------------|                              |--------|
| padding/cookie      | system dependent             |ello, wo|
|---------------------|                              |--------|
| storage for 'buffer'| 1 byte = sizeof(buffer)  ->  |   H    | 
|---------------------|                              |--------|
| padding/cookie      | system dependent             |  ? ? ? |
|---------------------|                              |--------|
| storage for 'below' | 2 bytes = sizeof(short)      |  0  0  |
|      ...            |
```

When I write into `buffer`, the first byte lands where it's supposed to be.  Then the next few bytes start writing over the 'padding/cookie' area.  Eventually that area is overflowed, and we go on overwriting the next higher thing, 'above'.

A quick check shows us that 27762 is how my machine interprets the characters `rl` in the middle of "world!" as a `short`.

Now, errors like this are stack buffer overflows, or "stack overflows".  A malicious user can make use of some instances of stack overflows to take control of your program and make it do entirely different things from what it was designed to do.  Exploiting a stack overflow is a tried and true hacking technique.

So much so that compiler writers and operating system designers have taken to a strategy of "defense in depth" to prevent stack overflows from being exploitable.  Ideally, if some user manages to overwrite a bad portion of the stack, the toolchain tries to do the only reasonable thing: crash immediately.

In this particular case, what the compiler does is to insert a special hard-to-guess value right after the storage for 'buffer' called a 'stack cookie.'  When it leaves `main`, it checks to see that the 'stack cookie' hasn't changed.  If it has, something naughty (probably a stack overflow) has happened, and so the program crashes immediately with the dialog you see.

How do we fix stack overflows?  Code defensively.  **Never** call `strcpy`, `strcat`, `sprintf` or their various friends.  Instead of using fixed size buffers (e.g. `char homeDirectory[33];`), use dynamic facilities such as `std::string homeDirectory;` to manage strings.  Used properly, it's impossible to overflow a `std::string` in such a way that unintended memory is overwritten.