# Getting an error in C++

Tags: c++

So [This](http://ideone.com/9riAm) is my code and I keep on getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSLEe.png).
I don't know what it is.
What I was doing before getting the error: Adding constructors and destructors to my classes.
What the error seems to be: The error windows points to line 52, `unsigned int _size; // number of account stored` however I do not see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: i can't see the error, but I think it is when you initialize the array [200] of AccountInfo.

Comment: The failing assertion is at line 52 of `dbgdel.cpp`, not line 52 of *your* code. You'll need to use your debugging skills to track down where in *your* code the failure is taking place.

Comment: As you've posted it, the code won't (shouldn't) compile at all. Perhaps what you're compiling has added some the missing headers? If you're going to use C++, I'd advise using C++, and (for example) replacing your use of `char *`, `strdup`, `strcmp`, etc., with `std::string`.

Comment: Please do not just post links. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94807/auto-ban-questions-that-use-pastebin

Comment: -1 for pasting your entire application's code. Please post [short, self contained, correct (compilable) examples](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091609/passing-parameters-and-giving-them-values-causes-runtime-error) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090756/c-sudden-error-2-stack-around-the-variable-users-was-corrupted). You should learn to use a debugger and/or replace all your C-style strings with `std::string`.

Comment: @Styne666 whenever I do that people just end up asking for the whole thing. It has happened before.

Comment: @Blastfurnace not it's not a duplicate. This time it's a different error.

Comment: A different error message but the same problem; raw C-strings and corrupting memory.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what the problem is?

Comment: You could spend some time learning to use the debugger that's included with Visual Studio. You can single-step through the code execution and watch the contents of your variables. It's a useful skill that will pay off greatly in the future.

Comment: Post the steps for re-creating the error. I know understanding/fixing these types of errors can be black magic for a novice, but for anybody to help you, you must make it very easy for them to get to the error quickly. I ran your code (which compiles with warnings on VC++) but I am staring at a blank console. Put down the steps that will lead me to the error. And as others have suggested, learn to use the debugger (it is not hard at all): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0

Comment: The program is run with a Command Argument. The command argument is a text file which is also in the description code. The program takes that code an the program runs fully until the end which is when the error appears.
I spent this night tracking the problem down and basically where the error happens is the constructor of the AccountInfo class when initializing the pointer char array of `_accounts` to null values. I think the mistake is in assigning values with the `= operator` so I tried changing it with `strcpy()` but I haven't gotten it working yet due to some errors that it gives me.

Comment: @Yokhen I doubt anyone has ever asked for your entire application's code. They have probably asked for the entire **relevant** code. The reason you should produce an 'sscce' is because often, in creating that sscce you will find the source of your problem (and therefore not waste other peoples time on silly mistakes). It also allows people to find the source of your problem more easily if you haven't found it already while creating the sscce.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that your `AccountInfo` class has a default constructor that doesn't initialize any of the pointers, but then its destructor wantonly calls `free` on those pointers. The best approach is to use `std::string` instead of `char *`, but if you're really insistent on using `char *`, then you at least need to initialize these pointers to `NULL` when they're not otherwise initialized.

That problem *can* cause this assertion failure (since Visual Studio, in debug mode, will helpfully initialize these pointers to special, easily-recognized trap-values — one of its nicer features IMHO), but I haven't looked through enough of your code to see if you might have other similar problems that can *also* cause it, so I don't know if this problem is what *is* causing the failure. But you need to fix it, regardless.